# Running a command repeatedly with different environment

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Let's say I want to run the process `foo` with different variables set, like:

```
FOO=1 foo
FOO=2 foo
FOO=1 BAR=7 foo
```

How can do do this without repeating the `foo` command repeatedly? E.g., by looping over the environment to set, like:

```
for e in 'FOO=1' 'FOO=2' 'FOO=1 BAR=7'; do
  env "$e" foo
done
```

That almost works, except in the case with `$e` equal to `FOO=1 BAR=1`, `FOO` gets set to `1 BAR=1` and `BAR` doesn't get set at all because `env` sees a single argument. I could use `env $e`, i.e., without quoting `e` - but then it doesn't work if the variable values have spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to get much shorter. If the issue is that the command you want to run is long, you might write a helper function, e.g.

```
r(){ env "$@" foo with lots of args ; }
r FOO=1
r FOO=2
r FOO=1 BAR=7
r FOO='1 BAR=7'
```

If there is a character you know is not going to be in either the names or the values of the environment variables you could use this to split, or you can attempt to quote the values correctly and use `eval`.

The question is why do you want to do this?

Comment: _The question is why do you want to do this?_ To avoiding the repeating the `foo` command (which is much more complex than just `foo`). Also to allow the possibility of having tested loops, e.g. 5 possible environments in one list, and 3 in another, and then nested loops to try all 5*3=15 combinations.

Comment: For the `repeating the foo command (which is much more complex than just foo)` case, the helper function is perfect. For nested loops it is perfectly possible to have one helper function for each level of nesting, so for a 3 way you could have `f1(){ r X=1; r X=2 ; r X=3 ; }`, and for the 15 way `f2(){ env Y=1 f1; env Y=2 f1 ; env Y=3 f1 ; env Y=4 f1 ; env Y=4 f1 ; }`. In most cases you do not need to use the `env` program.